# Add file to "Recent Files" from my script

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, dbus, cinnamon

I've got a Python script for retrieving PDF documents from a remote system and storing them locally. I run it manually from a Linux command line (using Ubuntu).

Whenever I store the file locally I would like to *somehow add it* to **Recent Files** so that it shows in the file dialog without me having to navigate through the directory structure to it.

How is this done? Is it some `dbus` magic? I don't need a complete solution, just a pointer where to look because I have no idea...

Thanks!

Comment: The file is stored at `~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel`. It's an XML-formatted file that you should be able to add entries to easily enough in python.

Comment: @DominicD Awesome, that’s the one! Thanks for that :)